# JBoss-database connectivity losts after 5 mins though procedure was executing in background, results in error

Tags: sql-server, database, jboss, timeout, connectivity

We have 2 environments, where we are calling one procedure from JSP page. I'm getting proper result in one environment after 7 mins as procedure execution time is 7 mins. But in another environment after 5 mins `JBoss-database` connectivity lost and results in error on `JSP`.

We are using `JBoss` EAP domain mode. Kindly provide solution.

Thanks.

Find below domain.xml content :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  <domain xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.5">  <extensions> <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.cmp"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.configadmin"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.jacorb"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxr"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.jsf"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.jsr77"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.messaging"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.modcluster"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.threads"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.web"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/> <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/> </extensions>  <system-properties> <property name="java.net.preferIPv4Stack" value="true"/> <property name="jboss.modules.system.pkgs" value="com.singularity"/> </system-properties>  <paths> <path name="LOG_PATH" path="E:\Apps\RedHat\Logs\Host01\${jboss.server.name}"/> </paths>  <management> <access-control provider="simple"> <role-mapping> <role name="SuperUser"> <include> <user name="$local"/> </include> </role> </role-mapping> </access-control> </management>  <profiles> <profile name="full-ha"> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.3"> <console-handler name="CONSOLE"> <level name="INFO"/> <formatter> <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/> </formatter> </console-handler> <file-handler name="TransActionLog" autoflush="true"> <level name="DEBUG"/> <file relative-to="LOG_PATH" path="transactions.log"/> <append value="true"/> </file-handler> <size-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true"> <level name="CONFIG"/> <formatter> <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/> </formatter> <file relative-to="LOG_PATH" path="server.log"/> <rotate-size value="50m"/> <max-backup-index value="30"/> <append value="true"/> </size-rotating-file-handler> <logger category="org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager"> <level name="TRACE"/> </logger> <logger category="com.arjuna" use-parent-handlers="false"> <level name="DEBUG"/> <handlers> <handler name="TransActionLog"/> </handlers> </logger> <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler"> <level name="WARN"/> </logger> <logger category="org.jboss.as.config"> <level name="TRACE"/> </logger> <logger category="sun.rmi"> <level name="WARN"/> </logger> <logger category="jacorb"> <level name="WARN"/> </logger> <logger category="jacorb.config"> <level name="ERROR"/> </logger> <root-logger> <level name="INFO"/> <handlers> <handler name="CONSOLE"/> <handler name="FILE"/> </handlers> </root-logger> </subsystem> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:cmp:1.1"/> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:configadmin:1.0"/> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.1"> <datasources> <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/omnicab" pool-name="omnicab" enabled="true" use-ccm="false"> <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://162.123.118.185:1433;databaseName=omnicab</connection-url> <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class> <driver>sqljdbc4.jar</driver> <pool> <min-pool-size>30</min-pool-size> <max-pool-size>500</max-pool-size> <prefill>true</prefill> <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min> <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy> </pool> <security> <user-name>OmniUserMO</user-name> <password>WrUthus4</password> </security> <validation> <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match> <background-validation>false</background-validation> </validation> <timeout> <blocking-timeout-millis>30000</blocking-timeout-millis> <idle-timeout-minutes>2</idle-timeout-minutes> </timeout> <statement> <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements> </statement> </datasource> <drivers> <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2"> <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class> </driver> </drivers> </datasources> </subsystem> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.1"> <global-modules> <module name="omnidocs_library" slot="main"/> <module name="org.jboss.remote-naming" slot="main"/> </global-modules> <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement> <jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>true</jboss-descriptor-property-replacement> </subsystem> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.4"> <session-bean> <stateless> <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/> </stateless> <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple" clustered-cache-ref="clustered"/> <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/> </session-bean> <mdb> <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="${ejb.resource-adapter-name:hornetq-ra}"/> <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/> </mdb> <pools> <bean-instance-pools> <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="100" instance-acquisition-timeout="10" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/> <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="100" instance-acquisition-timeout="10" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/> </bean-instance-pools> </pools> <caches> <cache name="simple" aliases="NoPassivationCache"/> <cache name="passivating" passivation-store-ref="file" aliases="SimpleStatefulCache"/> <cache name="clustered" passivation-store-ref="infinispan" aliases="StatefulTreeCache"/> </caches> <passivation-stores> <file-passivation-store name="file"/> <cluster-passivation-store name="infinispan" cache-container="ejb"/> </passivation-stores> <async thread-pool-name="default"/> <timer-service thread-pool-name="default"> <data-store path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/> </timer-service> <remote connector-ref="remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"/> <thread-pools> <thread-pool name="default"> <max-threads count="10"/> <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/> </thread-pool> </thread-pools> <iiop enable-by-default="false" use-qualified-name="false"/> <default-security-domain value="other"/> <default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="true"/> </subsystem> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.4"> <cache-container name="singleton" aliases="cluster ha-partition" default-cache="default"> <transport lock-timeout="60000"/> <replicated-cache name="default" mode="SYNC" batching="true"> <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/> </replicated-cache> </cache-container> <cache-container name="web" aliases="standard-session-cache" default-cache="repl" module="org.jboss.as.clustering.web.infinispan"> <transport lock-timeout="60000"/> <replicated-cache name="repl" mode="ASYNC" batching="true"> <file-store/> </replicated-cache> <replicated-cache name="sso" mode="SYNC" batching="true"/> <distributed-cache name="dist" l1-lifespan="0" mode="ASYNC" batching="true"> <file-store/> </distributed-cache> </cache-container> <cache-container name="ejb" aliases="sfsb sfsb-cache" default-cache="repl" module="org.jboss.as.clustering.ejb3.infinispan"> <transport lock-timeout="60000"/> <replicated-cache name="repl" mode="ASYNC" batching="true"> <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/> <file-store/> </replicated-cache> <replicated-cache name="remote-connector-client-mappings" mode="SYNC" batching="true"/> <distributed-cache name="dist" l1-lifespan="0" mode="ASYNC" batching="true"> <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/> <file-store/> </distributed-cache> </cache-container> <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4"> <transport lock-timeout="60000"/> <local-cache name="local-query"> <transaction mode="NONE"/> <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/> <expiration max-idle="100000"/> </local-cache> <invalidation-cache name="entity" mode="SYNC"> <transaction mode="NON_XA"/> <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/> <expiration max-idle="100000"/> </invalidation-cache> <replicated-cache name="timestamps" mode="ASYNC"> <transaction mode="NONE"/> <eviction strategy="NONE"/> </replicated-cache> </cache-container> </subsystem> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jacorb:1.3"> <orb socket-binding="jacorb" ssl-socket-binding="jacorb-ssl"> <initializers security="identity" transactions="spec"/> </orb> </subsystem> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxr:1.1"> <connection-factory jndi-name="java:jboss/jaxr/ConnectionFactory"/> </subsystem> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:1.1"> <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/> <bean-validation enabled="true"/> <default-workmanager> <short-running-threads> <core-threads count="50"/> <queue-length count="50"/> <max-threads count="50"/> <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/> </short-running-threads> <long-running-threads> <core-threads count="50"/> <queue-length count="50"/> <max-threads count="50"/> <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/> </long-running-threads> </default-workmanager> <cached-connection-manager/> </subsystem> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:1.1" default-stack="udp"> <stack name="udp"> <transport type="UDP" socket-binding="jgroups-udp"/> <protocol type="PING"/> <protocol type="MERGE3"/> <protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-udp-fd"/> <protocol type="FD"/> <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/> <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK"/> <protocol type="UNICAST2"/> <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/> <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/> <protocol type="UFC"/> <protocol type="MFC"/> <protocol type="FRAG2"/> <protocol type="RSVP"/> </stack> <stack name="tcp"> <transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp"/> <protocol type="TCPPING" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp"> <property name="initial_hosts"> ${jboss.cluster.tcp.initial_hosts} </property> <property name="timeout"> 2000 </property> </protocol> <protocol type="MERGE2"/> <protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp-fd"/> <protocol type="FD"/> <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/> <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK"/> <protocol type="UNICAST2"/> <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/> <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/> <protocol type="UFC"/> <protocol type="MFC"/> <protocol type="FRAG2"/> <protocol type="RSVP"/> </stack> </subsystem> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3"> <expose-resolved-model/> <expose-expression-model/> <remoting-connector use-management-endpoint="false"/> </subsystem> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1"> <jpa default-datasource="" default-extended-persistence-inheritance="DEEP"/> </subsystem> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsf:1.0"/> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsr77:1.0"/> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:1.1"> <mail-session jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default"> <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/> </mail-session> </subsystem> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.4"> <hornetq-server> <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled> <security-enabled>false</security-enabled> <journal-type>NIO</journal-type> <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>  <connectors> <netty-connector name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/> <netty-connector name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput"> <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/> </netty-connector> <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/> </connectors>  <acceptors> <netty-acceptor name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/> <netty-acceptor name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput"> <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/> <param key="direct-deliver" value="false"/> </netty-acceptor> <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/> </acceptors>  <broadcast-groups> <broadcast-group name="bg-group1"> <jgroups-stack>tcp</jgroups-stack> <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period> <connector-ref> netty </connector-ref> </broadcast-group> </broadcast-groups>  <discovery-groups> <discovery-group name="dg-group1"> <jgroups-stack>tcp</jgroups-stack> <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout> </discovery-group> </discovery-groups>  <cluster-connections> <cluster-connection name="my-cluster"> <address>jms</address> <connector-ref>netty</connector-ref> <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/> </cluster-connection> </cluster-connections>  <security-settings> <security-setting match="#"> <permission type="send" roles="guest"/> <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/> <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/> <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/> </security-setting> </security-settings>  <address-settings> <address-setting match="#"> <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address> <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address> <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay> <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes> <page-size-bytes>2097152</page-size-bytes> <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy> <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit> <redistribution-delay>1000</redistribution-delay> </address-setting> </address-settings>  <jms-connection-factories> <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory"> <connectors> <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/> </connectors> <entries> <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/> </entries> </connection-factory> <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory"> <connectors> <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/> </connectors> <entries> <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/> </entries> <ha>true</ha> <block-on-acknowledge>true</block-on-acknowledge> <retry-interval>1000</retry-interval> <retry-interval-multiplier>1.0</retry-interval-multiplier> <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts> </connection-factory> <pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-ra"> <transaction mode="xa"/> <connectors> <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/> </connectors> <entries> <entry name="java:/JmsXA"/> </entries> </pooled-connection-factory> </jms-connection-factories> </hornetq-server> </subsystem> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:1.1"> <mod-cluster-config advertise-socket="modcluster" connector="ajp"> <dynamic-load-provider> <load-metric type="busyness"/> </dynamic-load-provider> </mod-cluster-config> </subsystem> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.4"> <remote-naming/> </subsystem> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:1.1"> <connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/> </subsystem> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.1"/> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2"> <security-domains> <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default"> <authentication> <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional"> <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/> </login-module> <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required"> <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/> </login-module> </authentication> </security-domain> <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default"> <authorization> <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/> </authorization> </security-domain> <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default"> <authorization> <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/> </authorization> </security-domain> </security-domains> </subsystem> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.1"/> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.4"> <core-environment> <process-id> <uuid/> </process-id> </core-environment> <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/> <coordinator-environment enable-statistics="true" default-timeout="300"/> </subsystem> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.5" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false"> <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/> <connector name="ajp" protocol="AJP/1.3" scheme="http" socket-binding="ajp"/> <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true"> <alias name="localhost"/> <alias name="example.com"/> </virtual-server> </subsystem> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.2"> <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address> <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host> <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/> <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config"> <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM"> <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/> </pre-handler-chain> </endpoint-config> <client-config name="Standard-Client-Config"/> </subsystem> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:1.0"/> </profile> </profiles>  <interfaces> <interface name="management"/> <interface name="public"/> <interface name="unsecure"/> </interfaces>  <socket-binding-groups> <socket-binding-group name="full-ha-sockets" default-interface="public"> <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/> <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/> <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/> <socket-binding name="jacorb" interface="unsecure" port="3528"/> <socket-binding name="jacorb-ssl" interface="unsecure" port="3529"/> <socket-binding name="jgroups-mping" port="2" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45702"/> <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp" port="7600"/> <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp-fd" port="57600"/> <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp" port="55200" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45688"/> <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp-fd" port="54200"/> <socket-binding name="messaging" port="5445"/> <socket-binding name="messaging-group" port="2" multicast-address="${jboss.messaging.group.address:231.7.7.7}" multicast-port="${jboss.messaging.group.port:29876}"/> <socket-binding name="messaging-throughput" port="5455"/> <socket-binding name="modcluster" port="2" multicast-address="224.0.1.105" multicast-port="23366"/> <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/> <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/> <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/> <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp"> <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/> </outbound-socket-binding> </socket-binding-group> </socket-binding-groups>  <deployments> <deployment name="sqljdbc4.jar" runtime-name="sqljdbc4.jar"> <content sha1="ff439c53190a987d327165dec8b148f670cb7ca8"/> </deployment> <deployment name="wfs_ejb.jar" runtime-name="wfs_ejb.jar"> <content sha1="139596c21fbed3524bf304ccfe2a128706d406b4"/> </deployment> <deployment name="wfcustom_ejb.jar" runtime-name="wfcustom_ejb.jar"> <content sha1="00283b69bb89bcc15618e4c5cd28d88504513618"/> </deployment> <deployment name="wfs_timer_ejb.jar" runtime-name="wfs_timer_ejb.jar"> <content sha1="91b3a12fdd4bee9c3cd56e2a7da64e5b0823d7e3"/> </deployment> <deployment name="omnidocs_ejb.jar" runtime-name="omnidocs_ejb.jar"> <content sha1="d1bdbee452de8e84dac6dcdca60aaabb7aa4295a"/> </deployment> <deployment name="webdesktop.war" runtime-name="webdesktop.war"> <content sha1="71dbddf580c087e27232bbe88c7ddff72ce17815"/> </deployment> <deployment name="omnidocs.war" runtime-name="omnidocs.war"> <content sha1="0a59f26d6504fa196cb897d3ea0863ca8e051b44"/> </deployment> <deployment name="ofservices.war" runtime-name="ofservices.war"> <content sha1="1d95260b898c6d673f1776a45d52ff8e3c3ceedf"/> </deployment> <deployment name="customwebapp.war" runtime-name="customwebapp.war"> <content sha1="5089588eae2a6e373d86b307f030401238956d28"/> </deployment> <deployment name="processmanager.war" runtime-name="processmanager.war"> <content sha1="c50a55d7feba6a7ed68ef9bfe5e462a78cf437f9"/> </deployment> <deployment name="omniflowapproval.war" runtime-name="omniflowapproval.war"> <content sha1="ba676ebf2e38f1ca51a59bcc56e1ef83fc8d2572"/> </deployment> <deployment name="processmanager.war_ol" runtime-name="processmanager.war_ol"> <content sha1="301769eac66d03b7eb24271cc7b370b041405c14"/> </deployment> <deployment name="1stview.cab" runtime-name="1stview.cab"> <content sha1="6a47e2a8a73ba77507175721deb0aed08ea711db"/> </deployment> <deployment name="AnnotationToolbar.properties" runtime-name="AnnotationToolbar.properties"> <content sha1="382d32000b2869ee71895b746f4368fc673c559d"/> </deployment> <deployment name="DeleteHotFolder.jsp" runtime-name="DeleteHotFolder.jsp"> <content sha1="1493b777fbc51efe185a5b53ebde1efe5f7e437f"/> </deployment> <deployment name="ExtendSession.jsp" runtime-name="ExtendSession.jsp"> <content sha1="36aae2edb05f96bad955559a4ee1a6b2e47f0dc9"/> </deployment> <deployment name="ForceChangePassword.jsp" runtime-name="ForceChangePassword.jsp"> <content sha1="31c4934ecd9f0001b7abf635feb050c83c6a61f0"/> </deployment> </deployments>  <server-groups> <server-group name="OmniFlow_Cluster" profile="full-ha"> <jvm name="omnisrvr_conf"> <heap size="2048m" max-size="2048m"/> <permgen max-size="256m"/> <jvm-options> <option value="-javaagent:E:/Appdynamics/AppServerAgent-SUN/ver4.0.3.0/javaagent.jar"/> <option value="-Dappdynamics.agent.applicationName=OmniFlow"/> <option value="-Dappdynamics.agent.tierName=EBS_Omniflow"/> </jvm-options> </jvm> <socket-binding-group ref="full-ha-sockets"/> <deployments> <deployment name="ofservices.war" runtime-name="ofservices.war"/> <deployment name="omnidocs.war" runtime-name="omnidocs.war"/> <deployment name="omnidocs_ejb.jar" runtime-name="omnidocs_ejb.jar"/> <deployment name="sqljdbc4.jar" runtime-name="sqljdbc4.jar"/> <deployment name="webdesktop.war" runtime-name="webdesktop.war"/> <deployment name="wfcustom_ejb.jar" runtime-name="wfcustom_ejb.jar"/> <deployment name="wfs_ejb.jar" runtime-name="wfs_ejb.jar"/> <deployment name="wfs_timer_ejb.jar" runtime-name="wfs_timer_ejb.jar"/> <deployment name="customwebapp.war" runtime-name="customwebapp.war"/> </deployments> <system-properties> <property name="jboss.cluster.tcp.initial_hosts" value="162.123.228.158[7600],162.123.228.157[7600]" boot-time="true"/> </system-properties> </server-group> <server-group name="Reports_Cluster" profile="full-ha"> <jvm name="omnisrvr_conf"> <heap size="2048m" max-size="2048m"/> <permgen max-size="256m"/> <jvm-options> <option value="-javaagent:E:/Appdynamics/AppServerAgent-SUN/ver4.0.3.0/javaagent.jar"/> <option value="-Dappdynamics.agent.applicationName=OmniFlow"/> <option value="-Dappdynamics.agent.tierName=EBS_Omniflow"/> </jvm-options> </jvm> <socket-binding-group ref="full-ha-sockets"/> <deployments> <deployment name="omnidocs_ejb.jar" runtime-name="omnidocs_ejb.jar"/> <deployment name="sqljdbc4.jar" runtime-name="sqljdbc4.jar"/> <deployment name="wfcustom_ejb.jar" runtime-name="wfcustom_ejb.jar"/> <deployment name="wfs_ejb.jar" runtime-name="wfs_ejb.jar"/> <deployment name="wfs_timer_ejb.jar" runtime-name="wfs_timer_ejb.jar"/> <deployment name="processmanager.war" runtime-name="processmanager.war"/> </deployments> <system-properties> <property name="jboss.cluster.tcp.initial_hosts" value="162.123.228.158[7700],162.123.228.157[7700]" boot-time="true"/> </system-properties> </server-group> </server-groups>  </domain>
```

Comment: Are you expecting connectivity issue between jboss-DB due to network issue ? What exception is logged in log file ? Share domain.xml to check datasource configuration ?

Comment: There is no network issue. In log file FileNotFoundException is thrown due to lost connectivity.Please refer attached code of domain.xml

Comment: datasource configuration looks good, can you share complete exception you got.

Comment: ERROR_WINHTTP_TIMEOUT

12002

The request has timed out.